# Wireshark isn't showing all interfaces in Windows 7

Tags: wireshark

This is what I've done to check what was going on:

- Restarted PC
- Made sure WinPCAP driver (NPF) was installed
- Stopped and started NPF driver
- Running as admin

But it's only showing one interface, from VirtualBox. It won't show the main network connection.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you running wireshark as adminiteator?

Comment: @ott I could've swore that I put that in there originally. I'll edit it. But yeah, I'm running it as admin.

Comment: Have you seen Fassbinder's `Welt am Draht`? You might be in the 2nd level still.

Comment: Are you looking at it from insive the VM?